# Codeigniter wrong rotation

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

I'm using guillotine JS to manipulate the image that user want to upload, this JS library is giving me this `json: {"scale":1.4212, "angle":90, "x":83, "y":196, "w":400, "h":300}`, with this `json`, I can tell codigniter how I want the final image to be stored...
in side codeigniter I use this...

```
$resd = array();

$config['image_library'] = 'imagemagick';
$config['library_path'] = '/usr/local/bin/convert';
$config['source_image'] = $img;
$config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
$config['rotation_angle'] = 90;
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->rotate();

if (!$this->image_lib->rotate()){
    $resd['rotation'] = $this->image_lib->display_errors();
} else {
    $resd['rotation'] = 'Rotation pass';
}
```

The problem I have is that it doesn't matter what `rotation_angle` has, it always rotate the image to 180, that is the first step, after the rotation is done, I need to crop the image...
any help would greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
So, after the rotation got fixed, not the cropping doesn't want to work...
the idea is simple, first rotate the image if any, then crop the image, to crop the image I use this right after my first code...

```
$config['image_library'] = 'imagemagick';
$config['library_path'] = '/usr/local/bin/convert';
$config['source_image'] = $img;
$config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['x_axis'] = $xo;
$config['y_axis'] = $yo;
//$this->load->library('image_lib');
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->crop();    
if (!$this->image_lib->crop()){
    $ms['cropper'] = $this->image_lib->display_errors();
} else {
    $ms['cropper'] = 'Cropping done correctly';
}    
$this->image_lib->clear();
$config = array();
```

the `$xo` and `$yo` are integers, like 1 and 2, so, the cropping is not working, it does rotate the image properly but is not cropping it...

**UPDATE 2 8/16/2016 10:30PM**
Well, after playing with CI and it's library which the only thing that was useful was the rotation, I end up using Imagick to make the cropping part...

```
$imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($img));
$imagick->cropImage($wo, $ho, $xo, $yo);
if(!$imagick->writeImage($img)){
    $ms['cropper'] = 'Didn\'t worked';
} else {
    $ms['cropper'] = 'Now we can dance!';
}
```

And that did the trick!...

Comment: Remove `$this->image_lib->rotate();` line.

Comment: check roytuts.com/upload-and-rotate-image-using-codeigniter/   and   roytuts.com/upload-and-rotate-image-using-codeigniter/

Comment: @Tpojka thank you, that fixed the rotation but now is not cropping the image, after rotation I reset me `$config` var with `$this->image_lib-clear();` and `$config = array();` then I set the configuration for cropping, but it doesn't do it... `$config['x_axis'] = $x; $config['y_axis'] = $y; $this->load->library('image_lib');
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);` no luck there. thanks again.

Comment: Update your question so we could have a better code overview.

Comment: @Tpojka hi again, just update my question with the cropping code that I use...

Comment: Update 2 code looks just nice and clean to me. I am glad you did it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: adding 270 instead of 90!
In other words your angle must be divided from 360, so it will be the 360 - json angle

Specifies the angle of rotation when rotating images. Note that PHP rotates counter-clockwise, so a 90 degree rotation to the right must be specified as 270.

**There are 5 rotation options:**

```
90 - rotates counter-clockwise by 90 degrees.  
180 - rotates counter-clockwise by 180 degrees.  
270 - rotates counter-clockwise by 270 degrees.  
hor - flips the image horizontally.  
vrt - flips the image
```

Comment: As much as it is true, that does not apply in this case, I have used EXIF to get it's initial orientation, I even hard coded the orientation, I have try all possible combination, no luck, it keeps rotating the image to 180 no matter what I do.